# Fitting Double Gaussian in Python

Tags: python, astropy

I'm trying to write a code that performs a double Gaussian fit to a spectrum, but the fitted model gives a straight line.

```py
data=np.genfromtxt('74.r_e_20100124_3_1_1_2_one.fits.0001_corr_scopy.0001_spyk_cont.txt')

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

gaussian_1 = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=1.25, mean=0.97, stddev=1.)
gaussian_2 = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=1.28, mean=0.98, stddev=1.)
combined_gaussians = gaussian_1 + gaussian_2
g1 = combined_gaussians(x)

#Create a fitter which uses the Levenberg-Marquardt optimization and least-squares statistics

fitter = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
gauss_model = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=1., mean=0, stddev=1.)
model = fitter(gauss_model, x, g1)
print('Fitted parameters:', model.parameters)

plt.xlim(6500, 6600)
plt.plot(x, y, color='b', label='data')
plt.plot(x, model(x), color='r', label='fitted model')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.savefig('double_gaussian_fit.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this on a dataset that is less noisy? Because the peak is barely distinguishable from the background.
If you already know where the peaks roughly are, then it may be easier to just fit each peak seperatly.

Comment: Your model doesn't account for the background.  Try subtracting off the mean of the spectrum, then fitting your two Gaussian components.  You can also add a model component (say, a constant offset or a first order polynomial) to your model.